# Google App Engine: lose CSS on deployment?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a Google App Engine app that works fine on the dev server. However, when I upload it, the CSS is gone. The scripts are still there, however.

From `app.yaml`:

```
- url: /scripts
  static_dir: Static/Scripts

- url: /styles
  static_dir: Static/styles
```

From the base template:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/JQuery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/sprintf.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
```

What could be causing this? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The URL you're serving by specifying `- url: /scripts` is going to be something like `http://foobar.appspot.com/scripts`.  The URL you're *requesting*, given that you chose to use `href="./styles/style.css"`, will be the same only for top-level pages -- if you have that header on, say, `http://foobar.appspot.com/good/grief`, then you'll be requesting your styles from `http://foobar.appspot.com/good/styles/style.css` and the like.  Why would you *want* that?!  Use `href="/styles/style.css"`, without that extremely peculiar leading dot, and you'll be requesting the style from `http://foobar.appspot.com/styles/style.css` -- which looks to be where you want to be serving it from -- whatever page on `foobar.appspot.com` you request it from.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Alex's answer, I note you seem to be using capitalization inconsistently - some first letters are capitalized, and others aren't. Bear in mind that while Windows is not case-insensitive, most platforms are case-sensitive - so if you weren't strict about using the same capitalization for the same name everywhere, when you deploy, you will get a lot of 404s in place of expected files.